# Что за promise используется в fetch?

Tags: javascript

```js
fetch('/article/fetch/user.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    alert(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // application/json; charset=utf-8
    alert(response.status); // 200

    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(user) {
    alert(user.name); // iliakan
  })
  .catch(alert);
```

А что это за 2 then используется в promise? Нам на курсах только с одним показывали, две функции внутри resolve reject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) **возвращает** уже сформированный объект [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Далее, в примере, у результата вызова функции [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) вызывается метод [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). Результат вызова `then` так же является *новым* объектом [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). У которого опять вызывается **его** метод `then`.

Таким образом формируется цепочка вызовов, позволяющая последовательно выполнять асинхронные функции.

Функции `resolve` и `reject`, вероятно, в данном случае имелись, как параметры функции передающейся в конструктор `Promise`

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){...});
```

Так как в данном случае создание объекта `Promise` скрыто внутри вызова функции `fetch` эти функции не используются напрямую.